# Order Problem - Products lost from the invoice - Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice, payment

For the payment methods I am using the Mollie extension. A customer has placed an order, and has paid for it correctly. But, the information that I can see in the order view is the following:

[image]

As you can see, Magento says that the client has paid everything except € 5.42 (but this is not true because I received the total money).

And also Magento does not include one of my products in the invoice. You can see in the following picture how Magento includes a product in the invoice but not the last one.

[image]

In addition, I can not change the status of the order. If I try to issue an invoice, I receive the following error:

[image]

Any idea why this happens and how to solve it? I have 5 orders like this, with products that do not appear on the invoice and Magento says they must be paid (but I received the full amount of the order)

Comment: Do you have access to the database? Its going to be a database fudge to fix. As to cause could be your payment gateway you are using. Sorry no obvious fix to resolve.

Comment: Yes I have access to the database. What do you thing? How can I fix this problem? Is it a problem with Magento or my installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got access to db you should be able to work out the problem items using this query.

```sql
SELECT so.increment_id, so.entity_id, soi.order_id, soi.sku, soi.qty_ordered, soi.qty_invoiced 
FROM sales_order so, sales_order_item soi 
WHERE soi.qty_ordered != soi.qty_invoiced 
AND so.entity_id = soi.order_id
```

Update `qty_invoiced` where necessary

As for cause in my experience these problems are caused by 3rd party payment extensions.

Unfortunately I can't be more specific than that.

Were the problem orders all paid for the same way or is it just the one order?  If so might be worth reaching out the developer who produced the extension.  Although this could be a tricky problem to track down.

With regards to totals you are going to have to check the following amounts

```sql
SELECT `base_subtotal`, `base_subtotal_invoiced`, `base_tax_amount`, `base_tax_invoiced`, `base_total_invoiced`, `base_total_invoiced_cost`, `base_total_paid`, `base_total_qty_ordered`, `grand_total`, `subtotal`, `subtotal_invoiced`, `tax_amount`, `tax_invoiced`, `total_paid`, `subtotal_incl_tax` 
FROM `sales_order` 
WHERE increment_id = 000000002
```

where 000000002 is the `increment_id` of the affected order

You will have to manually update any values you find are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So the problem is with the payment platform and not with my Magento?

Comment: If I fix this problem in the database as you told me, what happens with the stock of the products? Would you have to update it manually or update it automatically?

Comment: Payment extension issue. Manual update.  You can do via backend.  No SQL.

Comment: I spoke with the Mollie company, and they tell me that the problem is not in their place because they have the correct data and they send the correct data to Magento. I can see the payments correctly in my Mollie dashboard and that a correct code is sent to Magento. Are you sure the problem is with the payment extension?

Comment: Yes.  It's the payment Mollie payment extension within Magento.  It's not invoicing the orders line items correctly.  Could be down to the syntax they've used to perform this action.  My best guess is that you got a table lock and the transaction responsible for updating the line item invoice value rolled back.  This then had a knock of affect when the process continued on and Magento calculated the order totals.  Not really a new issue.  Used to get this in Magento 1.  Some payment extensions are worse than others.

Comment: Sure, because we have a lot of orders paid correctly, but only a few that have not been recorded correctly and the products do not appear on the invoice, and therefore we have those few orders blocked. So what do you recommend? Change payment extension?

Comment: As a last resort.  Ideally you want to someone at Mollie with technical knowledge.  It's tricky with payment providers.  You have to persist until you get 2nd/3rd line support.   Ideally they need to look at your magento logs to diagnose what went wrong.  Then it's a business decision on you waiting for outcome/fix with occasional incorrect order vs switching provider.  How frequently does this occur? If for example you get 1 a day you could switch to 1 days transactions with another provider? See if you get same issue. If no issue this helps you build a case against using Mollie.

Comment: One more question, with your solution, I can close the orders, and add the invoice to the products, but if I consult the invoice, the products are still missing. How do I generate a new invoice with all the products?

Comment: You need to look at the `sales_invoice_item` table.  `parent_id` is the entity_id of the invoice.  You are missing an entry from there.  Sorry more manual calcuations I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you friend four your help. We are going to use Mollie and hope to have no more problems. If we have more problems, we will change Mollie for another payment extension. Could you recommend me some Magento 2.3.1?

Comment: Braintree. Comes with magento.  Very well tested.  That's about my only recommendation.  In the past had problems with Sagepay, Ingenico, Adyen and Worldpay.  Please mark as accepted and award points if you feel you have reached an answer.